# Symfony @Route annotation i18n: Is it possible to have a fallback for languages not explicitly declared?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, annotations

Using the @Route annotation in Symfony I can do the following:

```
/**
 * @Route({
 *     "en": "/{_locale}/registration",
 *     "de": "/{_locale}/registrierung",
 * },
 * name="registration",
 * defaults={
 *     "_locale":"%kernel.default_locale%"
 * },
 * requirements={
 *     "_locale":"^[a-z]{2}?$"
 * })
 */
public function defaultAction() { }
```

Visitors with english language can call `www.mysite.com/en/registration` and visitors with german language can call `www.mysite.com/de/registrierung` then.

Is it possible to declare a default for languages not explicitly declared? Such that a route for e.g. es or fr visitors works like `www.mysite.com/es/reg` or `www.mysite.com/fr/reg`?

Pseudo-Code:

```
/**
 * @Route({
 *     "en": "/{_locale}/registration",
 *     "de": "/{_locale}/registrierung",
 *     "_default_": /{_locale}/reg"
 * },
 * name="registration",
 * defaults={
 *     "_locale":"%kernel.default_locale%"
 * },
 * requirements={
 *     "_locale":"^[a-z]{2}?$"
 * })
 */
public function defaultAction() { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Currently](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#localized-routes-i18n) it impossible to do it via one annotation.
However you could create second fallback action. In addition them could be sorted by [priority](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-route-annotations-priority).

Example

```
/**
 * @Route({
 *     "en": "/{_locale}/registration",
 *     "de": "/{_locale}/registrierung",
 * },
 * name="registration",
 * defaults={
 *     "_locale":"%kernel.default_locale%"
 * },
 * priority="1",
 * requirements={
 *     "_locale":"^[a-z]{2}?$"
 * })
 */
public function defaultAction() {}

/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/registration",
 * name="registration_fallback",
 * priority="0",
 * requirements={
 *     "_locale":"^[a-z]{2}?$"
 * })
 */
public function fallbackDefaultAction() {
    $this->defaultAction();
}
```

Comment: Makes sense - at least it is possible. The only possibility I could still think of is extending `Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route` but I guess this is quite a lot of work?

Comment: Absolutely, I suppose that it's possible via extending built-in Symfony classes like `Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route`, `Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\AnnotationClassLoader`. But it looks complicated. In addition custom source code extending could be broken in future Symfony releases. Who knows, maybe Symfony will implement such or similar ability by community soon :)